# Google Calendar Api build

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to understand Google services and OAuth 2.0 while working on a Calendar app.
I encountered this issue and am not able to find a solution. Please let me know any way through this. In the code below, I get the warning that `calendar.builder` is deprecated.
What is another alternative?

```
public static Calendar build(GoogleCredential credentials) {
HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service;

service = Calendar.builder(transport, jsonFactory)
 .setApplicationName("Meetrbus/1.0")
    .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
      @Override
      public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) {
        CalendarRequest calendarRequest = (CalendarRequest) request;

        //TODO: Get an API key from Google's APIs Console:
       // https://code.google.com/apis/console.
        calendarRequest.setKey(<My Key>);
      }
    }).setHttpRequestInitializer(credentials).build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [`Calendar.Builder`](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/calendar/v3/index.html?com/google/api/services/calendar/Calendar.Builder.html) the constructor has changed a bit:

```
public Calendar.Builder(HttpTransport transport,
                    JsonFactory jsonFactory,
                    HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer)
```

So your code would be:

```
service = new Calendar.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credentials)
    .setApplicationName("Meetrbus/1.0")
    .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new JsonHttpRequestInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void initialize(JsonHttpRequest request) {
            CalendarRequest calendarRequest = (CalendarRequest) request;

            //TODO: Get an API key from Google's APIs Console:
            // https://code.google.com/apis/console.
            calendarRequest.setKey(<My Key>);
        }
    }).build();
```