# Google Calendar API Java Library - Cannot Resolve Symbol 'service'

Tags: android

I am currently trying to figure out how to use the Google Calendar API with Android. I got an authorization token, and now am attempting to import a calendar. Right now it tells me that the 'service' cannot be resolved, but I have imported all of the libraries using Gradle as far as I know.

Service is used under the loadCal function, and used like this:
Calendar calendar = service.calendars().get('pvhs.k12.nj.us_r6jaor04o80hpsaldf17civeio@group.calendar.google.com').execute(); ...In the BUild.gradle below you can see all of the libraries I have imported. Does anyone know what library service belongs to?

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.pvrhs.calendarapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.EventLog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.accounts.GoogleAccountManager;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar;
import com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Event;

import java.io.IOException;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static Context context;
    private String namesFor;
    public String works;
    public static final String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar";
    private String accountName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        context = getApplicationContext();
        getAccountNames();
    }

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;
            try {
                works = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(context, namesFor, "oauth2:" + scope);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            loadCal();
            return token;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
            TextView textViewToken = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textViewToken.setText("works" + works + namesFor);
        }
    };
    private void getAccountNames(){
        GoogleAccountManager googleAccountManager = new GoogleAccountManager(this);
        Account[] accounts = googleAccountManager.getAccounts();
        namesFor = (accounts[0].name);
        task.execute();
    }
    private void loadCal() {
        Calendar calendar = service.calendars().get('pvhs.k12.nj.us_r6jaor04o80hpsaldf17civeio@group.calendar.google.com').execute();
        Calendar.Events events = service.events().list('pvhs.k12.nj.us_r6jaor04o80hpsaldf17civeio@group.calendar.google.com').setTimeMin("2012-01-01T00:00:00Z").execute();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev75-1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-oauth2:v2-rev63-1.17.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add service as an attribute of your class, service is an object of `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar`.

Besides that you should initialize this attribute like this:

`service = Calendar.builder(transport, jsonFactory)
                        .setApplicationName("YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME")
                        .setHttpRequestInitializer(requestInitializer)
                        .build();`

Please take a look at these links below:

[troubles with google calendar builder service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958261/troubles-with-google-calendar-builder-service)

[Google Calendar Api buid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554340/google-calendar-api-buid)

Comment: Do you know what package the json factory comes with? I have tried importing com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory; com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator;, com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser; and com.google.api.client.json.JsonToken but it is still not imported.

Comment: Yes I know, jsonFactory is an instance of com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory. If you have more doubts, take a look at the links provided on my answer above.

Comment: Yes you are right, even on Google's Client Libraries sight there is a Jackson folder that contains JacksonFactory, however when I import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory; into Android Studio I am told 'jackson' is a symbol that cannot be resolved. Maybe an Android Studio bug?

Comment: Did you declared "jackson" as an attribute of your class?

Comment: I think I might have mislead you with the last comment. Basically, I imported com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory, it is imported before the Class tag begins, and I am given a symbol cannot be resolved error on the world jackson up there.

Comment: I saw that you created another question regarding "jackson" import problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513899/cant-import-com-google-api-client-json-jackson-jacksonfactory/22513969, could you mark this question as answered? I already made a response to you on the other question.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change it, I thought this thread was becoming off topic so wanted to close it. Thanks for all of your help.