# Can't Import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory, however I keep getting the "Cannot resolve symbol 'jackson' error. Has anyone else gotten this error while attempting to get this library? Maybe Google is deprecating it?

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you need Jackson? what is your minSDK ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory; missing in Google Drive example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231722/com-google-api-client-json-jackson-jacksonfactory-missing-in-google-drive-examp)

Comment: I need Jackson in order to use the Google Calendar API, SDK 14. 

I don't believe it is a duplicate because I am using Android Studio, which uses Gradle not Maven.

Answer (score 11):

Use this class for JacksonFactory instead of the previous one.

```
com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was using JsonFactory that was inside json instead of even going into Jackson, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

how are you setting this library, pleas take a look at these links:

**Setup:**
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/setup

**Tutorial:**
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate

Comment: Like it shows in the setup and tutorial you have posted, I am using the exact line: import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory; On that line itself that imports the library, it says that it  "Cannot resolve symbol 'jackson' ....On that line itself, not in the code.